# python flask apache import

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

hello i want to run a flask app on apache2 virtualhost with mod_wsgi

please see gist

i can import the module from python if im in /srv/http/dashboard and use python command and then from SonntagDashboard import app

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a22904852172526394f3da9c3feed8b

running python3.6 and apache 2.4 on manjaro (arch) linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told mod_wsgi where your project code is. Try changing to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard python-path=/srv/http/dashboard
```

BTW, do not use:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/http/dashboard
```

If you removed the `WSGIScriptAlias` people could download your code. Never setup `DocumentRoot` such that the directory for it is where your application code exists. Leave it unset so picks up Apache default, or create an empty directory and set `DocumentRoot` to point at it.

You also don't appear to be using a Python virtual environment. Ensure you read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: thanks for the informations, but now i'll get an error that render_template cant imported from flask

Comment: Have you before that point in code called a variable or something else ``flask``. Or do you have a ``flask.py`` in your code base. Anyway, different issue, so create a new question rather than trying to solve in comments. BTW, regarded as bad to link out to code/config in separate gist. Include relevant parts in your question.